# Retrieving records from Database in C#

Tags: c#, database

I have a database connected to my program, I want to search this database records looking for a value entered by user previously in a text box. Any one have an idea how to search the whole database for that value.

Any help is appreciated!
Thanks!

Comment: Going to need more information. What database? SQL Server? Oracle? What is your data access strategy? An ORM? Entity Framework? NHibernate? Straight ADO.NET?

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking to search the entire database tables for a specific piece of text then follow the guide here;

[Sql Server text search across all tables](http://vyaskn.tripod.com/search_all_columns_in_all_tables.htm)

Answer (score 1):

Two simple steps.

1. Get the value from the text box (depends on the language you are using)
2. Execute a select query on the database using the value from the text box as a parameter in the where clause of the query.

However - you need to clarify the question a lot more in order to get a more sensible answer.

What languages are you using?